# Is it a jagged array declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Could you please explain me the syntax behind `element` array declaration ? Is this a jagged array ? What are `Value` and `Type` in this case ?

```cs
 enum Color { Red = 1, Green, Blue }
 enum Theme { Dark = 1, Light, NotSure }

 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var elements = new[]
     {
         new { Value = 1, Type = typeof(Color) },
         new { Value = 2, Type = typeof(Theme) },
         new { Value = 3, Type = typeof(Color) },
         new { Value = 1, Type = typeof(Theme) },
         new { Value = 2, Type = typeof(Color) },
     };

     foreach (var element in elements)
     {
         var enumValue = Enum.ToObject(element.Type, element.Value);
         Console.WriteLine($"{element.Type.Name}({element.Value}) = {enumValue}");
     }
 }
```

Comment: `elements` is an array of *anonymous type's* instances

Comment: But it's only a simple one-dimensional array - it's neither an array of arrays (a jagged array) nor a multidimensional (rectangular) array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go from inner to outer: `elements` array's items

```
   new { Value = 1, Type = typeof(Color) }
```

are *anonymous type* instances (with two *properties*: `Value` of type `int` and `Type` of type `Type`); see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696(v=vs.90).aspx for details

`elements` array

```
   var elements = new[] {
     new { Value = 1, Type = typeof(Color) },
     new { Value = 2, Type = typeof(Theme) },
     ... 
   };
```

is a simple **1d** array of such *anonymous type* instances

Comment: Good answer. I would add that the array declaration works because the compiler interprets all the single elements to be of the same anonymous type, as they have the same properties with the same types.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a jagged array?

No. It is a one-dimensional array of anonymous objects.

> What are `Value` and `Type` in this case?

Properties of the anonymous class.